# Removing .php extension won't work

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I am using laravel, and the .php is removed using:

```
  # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

but then i am using the below to force www and ssl and it seems to break the above code and .php extension does not get removed anymore, what am i doing wrong?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 

#If neither above conditions are met, redirect to https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Full Code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 

    #If neither above conditions are met, redirect to https
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    #force www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What's the full .htaccess "code"?

Comment: Added full code, Also i noticed it is getting rid of the .php, but never gets rid of the .php for the index page

Comment: Well, the `index.php` is a file, so no redirect :)

Comment: I don't really deal with .htaccess much, but how do i just make it show index instead .php

Comment: Make a redirect if the `REQUEST_FILENAME` matches `index.php`

Comment: I don't really see anything that prevents getting rid of the extension.